# How can one page access a popup window's form data?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

#### Scenario

I have web page, let's call it *Window #1*, that contains a list of people including their name and email.

There will be a button on this page that user can click to open a new window (*Window #2*). The user will click the button, and a new window will open and the user will add additional people.

When they are finished adding users in Window #2, they would click "Save." Instead of using a POST to send this form back to the server, I want update the original page and model (Window #1) with the information entered in Window #2.

I'm looking for explanation of how you could solve this solution using combination of the MVC framework and/or JavaScript.

---

#### Current Knowledge

I'm fairly new to ASP.NET MVC and JavaScript, so I'm not sure whether this task is possible and what it would entail. I attempted to perform a `window.open` for *Window #2*, but then *Window #1* doesn't have access to *Window #2* and vice versa. I considered partial views as well, but I wasn't sure how that structuring would work.

I've attempted to research this situation, but I'm not entirely sure that my terminology is correct and thus I wasn't able to find much information regarding the topic.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should look at the [JQurey  post method](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) .  You can call it from your second window to post data to whatever database your using to persist your data.  You'd still need to figure a way to update the data on page 1...  Instead of opening a new window,  why don't you hide/show a form on page 1 and show it when the user clicks add.  Then once the post returns successfully, you can update the list with the data that's already on the form.

Comment: Rather than opening a second window, you could use a modal window to gather user information. When they close the modal you could reload the main window with the new data. This could be done really easy with bootstrap and jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child window *can* reference the parent window. The child window can then reference the DOM of the parent by using `window.opener`. An example from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp):

```
// Open a new window
var myWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=200, height=100");

// Write some text in the new window
myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");     

// Write some text in the window that created the new window            
myWindow.opener.document.write("<p>This is the source window!</p>");
```

Selectors can be used to modify the parent's DOM in the manner requested from the initial question.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the initial load of *Window#1* using a traditional MVC Get method. You could also use bootstrap [modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals) for *Window#2*. You would then use JQuery's [post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) method to send the new users to a `Post` method in your MVC controller. This method would ideally return something like a JSON objec with an updated list of users. You would then rebuild the list in your DOM when JQuery's `Post` method returns.

Alternatively, you could look into something like [Knockout.js](https://knockoutjs.com/) instead of using JQuery's `Post` method and manually rebuilding the user list. Knockout lends itself very well to scenarios like this.

Comment: This is a good recommendation. I later found out that you could solve this solution using new windows, which I preferred over modals for this solution. Thanks for the input!